# Question about measurability in complete measure space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is it true that
For a function $f$ mapping from complete measure space $(\Omega$ ,*F*,$\mu$) to ($R,L,m$) the lebesgue measurable space in real line. $f$ is measurable iff {$f\le t$}$\in$F.

Comment: No, that only works if we endow the real line with the Borel sets.

Comment: You need the pre-image of all Lebesgue measurable sets to be in $F$. Your statement only implies that the pre-image of all Borel sets are in $F$.